# How to generalize SpatialPolygons and conserving topology in R?

Tags: r, topology, generalization

I would like to generalize a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`  in R to make plotting more efficient. The polygons I have result in huge pdf plots that are slow to load and hard to integrate into a document.

I tried to use the `gSimplify` function from the `rgeos` package, but unfortunately it does not conserve the topology of the polygons.

Is there an alternative that I can use?

Comment: not really a solution, but could you plot to raster (jpg/png) instead? This stackoverflow question which discusses pdfsize reduction may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521299/reduce-pdf-file-size-of-plot-in-r/8524610#8524610

Comment: plotting the maps as raster image is an option, but whenever possible I would like to use vector graphics. The image quality is better when using vector graphics, especially when looking at the digital version of documents.

Comment: `gSimplify()` has an optional parameter `topologyPreserve` which defaults to `FALSE`. Have you tried setting that to `TRUE`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a discussion about this on [r-sig-geo](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-sig-geo@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg06316.html). For a definitive answer you should ask there, because there are people who know the insides of spatial R.

But, you can also do this in GIS desktop applications (export the shape using writeOGR command from rgdal or writePolyShape() from maptools) like QGIS, GRASS or SAGA.

For QGIS use Vector / Geometry Tools / Simplify geometries (I have tested and does not preserve the topology, but applied to Romania admin1 shapefile, looks fine with 2000 nodes).

For GRASS use v.generalize (read the manual for info about the algorithms, there are some).

For SAGA you must first convert the polygon to line (Shapes - Lines / Convert Polygons to Lines), then simplify lines (Shapes Lines / Line Simplification), and finally convert lines to polygons (Shapes - Polygons / Convert Lines to Polygons). I have tested this and the results has the topology preserved.

Answer (score 2):

There is now the wonderful `rmapshaper` package by Andy Teucher that includes a simplify function that "performs topologically-aware multi-polygon simplification".

From their github repo, a usage example:

```
states_simp <- ms_simplify(states_sp)
```

where `states_sp` is a `spatialPolygons*` object.

See the package README for more information: https://github.com/ateucher/rmapshaper