# v.generalize not working QGIS 2.14 "The following layers were not correctly generated" polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, features

I am trying to generalize a polygon layer using the v.generalize algorithm in QGIS 2.14. While it works for linear features, polygon features are refused by the program. Might anyone know, what the specific problem in this case is? The Data is referenced in DHDN GK 4.

I don't want to do the workaround using linear features, but rather would like to directly generalize (chaiken) the polygon features.

[image: Generalize not working]

Comment: If you do not want to use this other tool https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/simplifygeometries.html you should perhaps try this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83855/simplifying-adjacent-polygons-using-qgis-simplify-geometries-tool.

Answer (score 2):

The tool works for line feature class only. Polygon generalization is not yet supported. Based on the [tool description](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.generalize.html):

> v.generalize is a module for the generalization of GRASS vector maps.
>   This module consists of algorithms for **line** simplification, **line**
>   smoothing, **network** generalization and displacement (new methods may be
>   added later)

You receive an error because the input is polygon not line feature.