# Mapshaper simplify equivalent in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, generalization, mapshaper

I was shown the simplify function of https://mapshaper.org/, which removes unnecessary vertices in polygons. Now I'm looking for a similar function in QGIS and found GRASS generalisation. Since I'm not profound on generalisation algorithms and there are alot of them in GRASS generalisation could anybody tell me which algortihm I have to use to get an equal result?

What Mapshapers simplify does:

After you loaded a file you have a slider to simplify the polygon(s) The great part about is that it removes redundant vertices first and only after that starts to change the geometry. Additionaly the shared borders between polygons stay the same and you get no holes between them.

[image: loaded shapefile]

[image: with ~50% vertices removed]

[image: high generalisation with most vertices remove]

Comment: What is the meaning of basepoint in this context?

Comment: I mean points which were defined during digitalisation and I want to remove the redundant ones

Comment: i guess node is what I meant. Will edit it.

Comment: What Mapshaper does for a polygon  layer is more than just to remove some vertices https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Topology-Issues. Perhaps you find usable hints from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83855/simplifying-adjacent-polygons-using-qgis-simplify-geometries-tool.

Comment: After you loaded a file you have a slider to simplify the polygon(s) The great part about is that it removes redundant vertices first and only after that starts to change the geometry. Additionaly the shared borders between polygons stay the same and you get no holes between them.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to scan a long comment trail for critical information.

Comment: Screenshots (befor/after) are often helpful.

Comment: In GRASS GIS, use v.generalize (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.generalize.html#simplification-example) for topological simplification/smoothing.