# How to generalize shape with PyQGIS without much Distortion in the shape?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7, generalization

[image]

I was trying to generalize the the inner boundaries of the polygon. Looking for a PyQGIS solution for that any other possible python solution will be fine.

I tried convex hull and simplify geometry that available in qgispy but the results create distortion in the sape. For Convex hull i got overlapping polygon which is not suitable for analysis and for general simplification the shape distorted by a lot make the polygon unuseable.

So i seek help if anyone knows any way to simplify the inner boundaries and make those boundaries with less ups and downs,more like a straight line. any link or suggestion will do a lot for me.

Comment: did you see this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20799/generalizing-polygon-file-while-maintaining-topology-in-qgis

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found a R library "rmaphaper" to ease my task.