# Geopandas simplify results in gaps between polygons

Tags: shapely, geopandas, simplify

The goal is to simplify the geometries of a shapefile containing multipolygons. However, when I use Shapely's simplify in [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/reference.html?highlight=simplify#geopandas.GeoSeries.simplify), the result contains gaps between the polygons. I was hoping that preserve_topology would avoid this? How can I avoid or fix the issue?

```
gdf_simplified = gdf.copy()
gdf_simplified["geometry"] = gdf.geometry.simplify(tolerance=TOLERANCE,preserve_topology=True)
```

my geoDataFrame is in in `{'init': 'epsg:4326'}`and I use a tolerance of 360/43200 which corresponds to 30" degrees (appr. 1 km at the equator).

[image]

The old polygons are displayed using the black line. The new resulting polygons are depicted using colors.

For now, I was able to revert to [MapShaper](https://mapshaper.org/) and get simplified shapes without the gaps. However, I would prefer a python based approach.

Comment: Maybe converting to TopoJSON might help but I've never used that before.

Comment: Preserverve topology does not do that for the whole layer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20799/generalizing-polygon-file-while-maintaining-topology-in-qgis. You need some topology-aware tool for that.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned, you need a topology aware simplification algorithm. For this I use the [topojson](https://github.com/mattijn/topojson) package:

```py
gdf = <geopandas dataframe>

import topojson as tp

topo = tp.Topology(gdf.to_crs({'init':'epsg:3857'}), prequantize=False)
simple = topo.toposimplify(1).to_gdf()

# optional
simple.plot()
```