# Resolve Intersecting areas in shapefile

Tags: python, geoprocessing, ogr2ogr

I combined two shapefiles and noticed that the polygons didn't overlay perfectly.
How can I resolve these intersections to snap to their closest neighbours?

[image]

This is a closer look at the intersections:
[image]

I brought these files together using mysql, however I've been using ogr2ogr and python also.

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20799/generalizing-polygon-file-while-maintaining-topology-in-qgis help?

Comment: unfortunately that's using a software i don't have. I was hoping there was some kind of cleaning tool in ogr2ogr

Answer (score 1):

You have two polygons overlapping. They both represent the same area/district . When you merge the two layer there is a difference in the shape of the 2 polygons . This is most probably due to the fact that they have been generated by 2 different people. I suggest that before you merge the 2 shapefiles that you remove one polygon the one that you do not want form the original file then merge the two.

The easiest way would be to use a Desktop GIS Software like QGIS then merge the two. Unless if you require to do this automatically or programmatically then it would be more tedious to achieve.